# Succulent clean up and growth

Tags: plant-care, succulents

I've learnt from a YouTube video that succulent "leaves" can be cleaned with milk and that would remove water stains as well. I wanna know if this can cause any harm to the leaves. My succulent has gotten very dusty and I would like to clean it up. 
Another thing I wanna know about is why it isn't growing. It has been the same since i bought it (which was around 3 months ago. There has been no growth at all. Is this normal? Are they slow growing plants? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Milk? Really? Sure, go ahead, YouTube is never wrong. I'd suggest water, personally. You don't mention where you are, but if you are in the northern hemisphere you plant is probably dormant or growing very slowly. Once days get longer and warmer it should wake up and grow.

A few questions: does that pot have a drain hole? If not, it needs one ASAP. Either drill one in that pot or use a pot with holes. What potting media are you using? You should use cactus/succulent soil with no or very little peat. Add some perlite or pumice to loosen things up and provide airspace.

Comment: I'm from South India. The pot does have drainage holes and I will surely add some perlite into the soil. It sits in plain garden soil that drains off quickly. No peat. Recently I've noticed that one of its roots has begun to rot. Do you think it's because of the potting medium?

Comment: YouTube is never wrong? Seriously?

Comment: No, never. BTW, I have a bridge you may be interested in.